# Confusion on disk types in gcloud when creating a new disk

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

So I'm looking at the [disk types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/) available on the google cloud platform and they have [Persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs) and [Local SSD disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#localssds) (from reading their documentation). After dreading the docs I go to create a disk the disk types are labeled as 'SSD Persistent disk' and 'Standard Persistent disk'. They seems to be named different here to in the docs. I just want a confirmation that:

SSD Persistent disk = Local SSD disk

Standard Persistent disk = Persistent disks

I'm new to running VMs on a cloud platform for hosting your own site and im trying to wrap my head around the different options available for all the different settings and why you would choose one over the other..

I'm trying to learn the different disks available and what they do but when I go to actually create a disk the types they have avaliable aren't even the same as the ones they list in the docs. I figured they could be the same but named different for whatever reason so I wanted to come here and confirm if thats the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have 2 different disk types to choose from when setting up a GCE instance:

Persistent disks can either be regular persistent disks, which could be HDD, or SSD's.
Local disks, which are not persistent are always SSD's.

Like you can read in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/) using local SSD's only allow up to 3TB to be stored on the disks while the Persistent disks allow up to 64 TB.

SSD's are also more expensive per GB used. The upside for SSD's however is that they allow higher throughput and lower latency.

There's several other things to note, everything there is to be found about GCE disks can be found in the aforementioned docs.

Answer to your original question:

Persistent disk = Standard Persistent Disk or SSD persistent disk and non-persistent disk = Local SSD

Comment: This answer is misleading.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sure, see my later answer. I agree that the naming of these things is not the best and can cause confusion. Especially if you have to understand AWS's terminology and GCE's and Azure's.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Local SSD disks are *not persistent*.

Comment: @QuinnComendant You're correct, I've updated my answer, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 23):

Your choices are:

1. local SSD = locally-attached to the VM, SSD
2. standard persistent = network-attached, persistent, HDD**
3. SSD persistent = network-attached, persistent, SSD

Type 1 is lower latency than types 2 and 3, because type 1 is physically attached to the VM.

Type 2 and 3 persist beyond instance stop/delete. Type 1 does not.

Type 2 and 3 are durable/redundant (Google replicates them, like Raid 1). Type 1 is not.

Type 2 and 3 can be attached to multiple VMs simultaneously (in read mode). Type 1 cannot.

** nowhere does Google actually indicate afaik that standard persistent is actually HDD, just that it is not SSD, so it may not be guaranteed to be HDD.

You can see more specific data at [Storage Options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/), but in summary:

- local SSD is the fastest (by far)
- SSD persistent has much higher read/write IOPS than standard persistent
- SSD persistent is more expensive (4x) than standard persistent

Comment: Anybody know how to add number local ssd disk count/type during the creation of cluster using KOPS?

Comment: I still don't understand which one is better? I understand that the local SSD has low latency, but what is better in which situation?

Comment: @jarmod Great, thank you so much for the quick response :)